# Separation axiom implied by semidecidability of comparison

Tags: general-topology, computability, separation-axioms, decidability

I am studying computable analysis. What I'm fascinated by is the analogy between computable analysis and general topology: [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_analysis#Analogy_between_general_topology_and_computability_theory)

> Semidecidable sets are analogous to open sets.

So I treat them essentially the same.

> Discrete sets in topology are analogous to sets in computability where equality between elements is semi-decidable.

This would actually make every set decidable, for every set is clopen in discrete topology.

But I'm puzzled with:

> Hausdorff sets in topology are analogous to sets in computability where inequality between elements is semi-decidable.

If the "inequality" refers to $≠$, this would mean every cofinite set is open, and thus every finite set is closed. Doesn't that mean the space is $T_1$, but not necessarily $T_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying that $\neq$ is semi-decidable for a space $\mathbf{X}$ is the effective counterpart of saying that the complement of the diagonal $\{(a,b) \mid a \neq b\} \subseteq \mathbf{X} \times \mathbf{X}$ is open. This is a standard example of a condition equivalent to being Hausdorff.

You do need to be careful though with discreteness: In classical topology discrete indeed implies Hausdorff, and you thus don't need to distinguish between equality being semidecidable and equality being decidable. In the effective world, there is a difference though. A counter-example is the quotient of $\mathbb{N}$ by the equivalence relation $\sim$ where $a \sim b$ iff $a = b$ or $a,b \in H$ where $H$ is the Halting set. This space has semidecidable equality, but not decidable equality (so it is computably discrete, but not computably Hausdorff).

As you mention $T_1$, it turns out that that does not have a clear effective counterpart. In fact, some statements that look like computable counterparts are already the computable counterpart to being Hausdorff.

If you want to read more on the computability/topology analogy, I'll be so forward and advertise my article here: [Journal](https://content.iospress.com/articles/computability/com049) [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.3763)

Comment: Sorry for late comment, but I don't follow the semidecidable equality vs. decidable equality. The cause of the contrast seems to be because the quotient map is not computable. Is this right?

Comment: The quotient map $q : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}/\sim$ is computable (trivially so, as it is realized by the identity). But that has no impact on decidability of equality (a quotient of space can have much weaker separation axioms than the original). But $\mathbb{N}/\sim$ is built explicitly in a way that semideciding inequality is the same thing as enumeration the complement of $H$.